# ListView header not working as expected?

Tags: java, android, listview

In my Android application, I have a class that extends `ListActivity` and the class itself is a list. (The application is  a ToDo list).

And I want to add a static header (an image) on top of the list that *will scroll* with the list. When I use `addHeaderView(imageView, null, false)` the image is displayed, but it won't work as expected: it will be clickable *and* perform the action of the first list item. The actual first list item performs the second list items's function, and so on.

Any idea why this is and what can I do to resolve it?

Here is my code of the `onCreate()` function:

```
private ListView lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lv = getListView();

    ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
    im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.android_robot);
    lv.addHeaderView(im, null, false);

    refreshList();

    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            goToTasks(String.valueOf(getListAdapter().getItem(position)));
        }
    });

    lv.setCacheColorHint(0);
    lv.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

    registerForContextMenu(lv);

    int[] colors = {0x00FF9900, 0xAAFFCC00};
    lv.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, colors));
    lv.setDividerHeight(2);
}
```

And the code for my `Adapter` (This is in the `refreshList()` method):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, populateList());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Note: The `populateList()` method returns an array of `String`s which is set to the `Adapter` as in the above code.

If any more code or screenshots are needed, ask in the comments.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**

I just found a temporary solution: Just adding `-1` after the `position` of,

```
goToTasks(String.valueOf(getListAdapter().getItem(position)));
```

will work, but that doesn't answer the real reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to call getListView() so many times without reason. Just type this `ListView lv = getListView();` in the beginning and then use lv to populate your list, set listeners and add the header view.

Hope this works!

Comment: Tried it, no luck.. The same thing happens.. :(

Comment: Can you update the code with this change and also show the adapter that you use?

Comment: I updated that code and added a bit more details. Please see the question now.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Static Header not Clickable use the below code in onItemClick

if(position==0){

view.setOnClickListener(null);

view.setOnLongClickListener(null);

view.setLongClickable(false);

}

Comment: That's not the problem, I can make it not-clickable by just passing `false` as the 3rd parameter to the `addHeaderView()`. It would make it unclickable, but still the first list item does the second's action and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Static Header not Clickable you can inflate another layout over the listview.
You can use something like this code:

```
list.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_list, null), null, false);
```

Comment: See the comment I have posted for krishna 's answer.

Comment: Sorry but I dont' think to understand. You want an unclickable headet only the first item is what??

Comment: I get an unclickable header without any problem. **But** when I click the first list item below the header, the action of the second list item is executed. And when the second is clicked, the third happens. Say for example, if 1st item is clicked "A" _should_ be shown and for 2nd "B" _should_ be show. What really happens is, when 1st is clicked, "B" is shown. When 2nd is clicked, "C" is shown, and so on..